# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) while deploying war from Jenkins to tomcat

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, tomcat

I am trying to deploy war file from jenkins (running on localhost:8080), on to tomcat 8(running on localhost:8081). But deployment fails due to

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Complete deployment log:

```
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Attempting to deploy 1 war file(s)
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Deploying /var/jenkins_home/workspace/hello-world/webapp/target/webapp.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context /hello
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/hello-world/webapp/target/webapp.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:188)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1905)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:169)
    ... 18 more
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:882)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:895)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:169)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1075)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1058)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1905)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I did google and made sure that all the possible reasons are addressed:

- added user with manager-script role on tomcat, and provided same user credentials for the jenkins job.

I tried using both the user for deployment. But failed.

- Also, `value` tag in the */usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml* and */usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml* are commented.

I think this has to do something with how docker networking works. Checked the network details as below:

```
"804ae533566e76674c10273b0a8b7849a97d7c294da0bac21e41ce0708ae905f": {
                "Name": "jenkins",
                "EndpointID": "6623ba48dd663a1cbd16cbd50351c0655cbee3bb2829d4355573cd5d628b4095",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f2befbc710302d9e3f00c8e29979738dc7e786626a01241df19fb04c8d808cf2": {
                "Name": "tomcat1",
                "EndpointID": "7d258c072a39fbf8b2e52b7fec4be2093eb2d31508a3f510ab0466f8ad077381",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, did you find a working solution?

Comment: @aironman not really.